# Touchscreen on HP Envy is not working with 18.04

Tags: touchscreen

I have HP ENVYx360 and recently I installed Ubuntu 18.04 recently and my touch screen is not working anymore. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue. I have an AMD cpu with graphics. As far as I know the touch screen is not supported yet. I have only recently been able to use my hdmi out port after an update. Does your OS crash a lot? I continually get crashes related to AMD on this thing.

Comment: my OS recently crashed during its usual updation and now I install windows.

Comment: i will install ubuntu shortly, but my touchscreen is perfectly working in windows